# Why sanitizing and escaping are recommended to be done separately

Tags: php

I have read a number of articles about php security, most of them recommend that I only need to sanitize user input when I want to output it, and if I want to just store it in my database, i only need to escape it using PDO.

why it is not wise/good to sanitize and escape the user input all at once and then store it in my database, and when I want to output it I just query it from my database and display it to the user without any sanitization or escaping, because I already did all of that when the user had entered his data in first time?

Comment: It would help if you could reference a few of the articles.

Comment: @ Bradley Ross, please see the section titled "When to escape output". https://www.inanimatt.com/php-output-escaping.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same data may be used for multiple applications.  The appropriate type of sanitization may be different for different applications.  There may be some use cases where the social security number or credit card number may be required, while it should be removed for other applications.

You need to escape the data going to the database so that characters in the data are not interpreted as commands to the PHP processor or database system.  You may also need to escape the data coming out of the database if it is to be used as part of an HTML document.

A case for sanitization of the data before entering the database would be that some information should not be known to the application.  For example, some systems would examine free text data and remove items that appear to be social security numbers because it would be a security violation to have social security numbers in the database.